# Strictly Concave Function over non-convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have to optimize a function $f$ over a set $S \subset X$.
We know that $f$ is non-negative, continuos and strictly concave over $X$. We have that  $S$ is compact but not convex.

**By Extreme Value Theorem $f$ attains its maximum over $S$.**

My question is this extremum unique?

I know that if $S$ is convex than the maximum is unique. However, in my case $S$ in not convex.

What further assumption on $f$ will guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: What is $X$? There are not that many non negative concave functions over a vector space.

Comment: I am working with the space of probability distributions. But for the purposes of this question I don't think it matters.

Comment: Take $X=(-2,2) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $S = \{\pm 1 \}$ and $f(x) = 4-x^2$ which is strictly concave. The maximum value $3$ occurs at both points of $S$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. But I how to extend it or find sufficient conditions for any $f$ that I mentioned.

Comment: The problem is not $f$, it is $S$.